# Filter EntityList with Liquid

Tags: dynamics-crm, entity, liquid, adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals

Being new to liquid and entitylists, I see this as the SQL equivalent to `select * from vehicle` and am trying to work out how to add a where clause to make  `select * from vehicle where keeper = {{userid}}` and for the life of me, I can't find how to do that.

Is there an easy way to apply a simple filter?

```
    {% entitylist name:"Vehicle" %}
      {% entityview %}
        <p>Found {{ entityview.total_records }} records</p>
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            {% for e in entityview.records -%}
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>Keeper <strong>{{ e.keeper }}</strong></p>
                    <p>Name <strong>{{ e.vehiclemake }}</strong></p>
                    <p>Fuel Card <strong>{{ e.vehiclemodel }}</strong></p>
                    <p>VRM <strong>{{ e.vehicleregistration }}</strong></p>
                </td>
              <tr>
            {% endfor -%}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      {% endentityview %}
    {% endentitylist %}
```

In the link on the answer from Arun, it is suggested to filter the entity list by the currently logged in user, which seems to be obvious, but when I went to the list, to try that, I don't hvae the option to add **Contact (parentcontactid)**

[image]

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: @ArunVinoth please see the addiion to the OP that I added (had to add it there as I wanted to include the picture)

Comment: looks like you don’t have owning portal user - contact lookup in your custom entity.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to filter the entity list in portal, using portal user/parent contact attribute configuration or even fetchxml tag in liquid template.

[The trick from Nick](https://readyxrm.blog/2017/11/30/filter-a-dynamics-365-portal-entity-list/) is another no-code configuration only solution.

Basically we can create a dummy contact, use it to filter the view and let the portal engine replace the current portal user in runtime.

[image]